# LESS compilation (Grunt) or cache issue

Tags: less-css, grunt, magento-2.1.2

I have started using Grunt, but encountered an issue. I am trying to change styles in custom theme via one of the LESS files, but nothing happens. It worked once, but it doesn't now, and I don't know why.

Task: change _grid-col.less
Result expected: style change on front-end.
Current result: style changes on front-end from an earlier customization (but not from the last).

Here's what I've tried:

- Set Magento Dev mode;
- clear directories var/di/, var/generation/, /var/view_preprocessed/,  , /pub/static/frontend/Codazon/
- flush cache
- change _grid-col.less
- grunt clean:outdoor
- grunt exec:outdoor
- grunt less:outdoor --force (force because the theme has some errors. That didn't prevent it from working earlier...)

Also, I tried:
- setup:static-content:deploy --theme Codazon/fastest_outdoor lt_LT en_GB
- clear browser cache

Here is my `themes.js` file for Grunt:

> ```
>     module.exports = {
>     outdoorlt: {
>        area: 'frontend',
>         name: 'Codazon/fastest_outdoor',
>         locale: 'lt_LT',
>         files: [
>             'css/source/_theme',
>             'css/source/_variables',
>             'css/source/layout/_blocksidebar',
>             'css/source/layout/_footer',
>             'css/source/layout/_header',
>             'css/source/layout/_slider',
>             'css/source/layout/_homestore',
>             'css/email-fonts',
>           'css/source/components/_modals_extend',
>             'css/source/_sources'
>         ],
>         dsl: 'less'
>     },
>     outdoor: {
>        area: 'frontend',
>         name: 'Codazon/fastest_outdoor',
>         locale: 'en_GB',
>         files: [
>             'css/source/_theme',
>             'css/source/_variables',
>             'css/source/layout/_blocksidebar',
>             'css/source/layout/_footer',
>             'css/source/layout/_header',
>             'css/source/layout/_slider',
>             'css/source/layout/_homestore',
>             'css/email-fonts',
>             'css/source/components/_modals_extend',
>             'css/source/_sources'
>         ],
>         dsl: 'less'
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> 'css/email-fonts',
>   'css/source/components/_modals_extend',
>   'css/source/_sources' are from parent theme. _grid-col.less is imported via _sources.less

I recently changed the workflow to client-side, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that it was Varnish what stopped from cleaning cache. When my webserver started using more hosts, Varnish purge wouldn't work with Magento flush. I had to change some settings in `default.vcl`. In my case, I added `set req.http.host = "outpro.lt";`

More details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334023/configure-multiple-sites-with-varnish

In addition, I have changed Varnish settings in Magento, `default.vcl` and `/etc/sysconfig/varnish` host or listen address (according to file) to my host instead of IP.

UPDATE

It does not work as supposed to.. Anyway, running command `service varnish restart` always cleans the cache.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

**The first you could try**

1. go to the backend under system-> cache management
2. under additional cache management (the last section of this site) you have the point with the explaination: Themes JavaScript and CSS files combined to one file.
3. press the button
4. use the cpmposer with the compile commands

   - -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
   - bin/magento index:reindex
   - bin/magento cache:clean

**The second you could try**

use the cpmposer with the compile commands

- -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
- -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
- bin/magento index:reindex
- bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I haven't achieved any changes with these solutions. The composer commands you provided have bad syntax. I am quite new to Magento maybe I have mistaken. Anyway, it's strange that when I delete pub/static/frontend/Codazon content and refresh website, it uses pub/static/frontend/Codazon/fastest_outdoor/en_GB/css/styles-l.css which doesn't exist on server.

Comment: Where is the bad syntax? And with your problem with your less file:

Comment: Im sorry, forgot the last part: It use the cached file or the theme-file. Did you look at the vendor folder?